# Numbers that are different repeated digits in different bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, natural-numbers

> ***Q***. What are all the numbers $n$, such that each is represented
>   as repeated digits—different digits—in two different bases $b_1$ and $b_2$.

So in base $b_1$,
$$
n_{b_1} = c c c \cdots c \;,
$$
and in base $b_2$,
$$
n_{b_2} = d d d \cdots d \;,
$$
and $c$ and $d$ are digits with $c \neq d$.

Such numbers exist: for example,
$$
777_{10} = 3333_{6} \;.
$$
I would be interested in a characterization of such 
$\{n, b_1, b_2 \}$.

An obvious extension is: repeated digits in $k$ bases
$b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k$.
**Added.** It would be especially nice to find a number
such that:
$$
1 1 \cdots 1 _{b_1} =
2 2 \cdots 2 _{b_2} =
3 3 \cdots 3 _{b_3} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Related to https://oeis.org/A125134 and https://oeis.org/A288783

Comment: But there are so many, even if you leave out examples where one representation in $(11)_b$; $15=(33)_4=(1111)_2$, $18=(33)_5=(22)_8$, $21=(33)_6=(111)_3$, $24=(44)_5=(33)_7=(22)_{11}$, $26=(222)_3=(22)_{12}$, and so on.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A167783 lists "Numbers that are repdigits with length > 2 in more than one base" and gives some links and references. Also https://oeis.org/A290869 lists "Numbers that are repdigits with length > 2 in more than two bases."

Comment: What is the underlying motivation for this question?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris: Curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

In base $b$ the numbers that have digit $d < b$ repeated $n$ times can be described as:

$$d \cdot\frac{b^n - 1}{b - 1}$$

Thus your question can be simplified to finding integer solutions for:

$$d \cdot\frac{b_1^n - 1}{b_1 - 1} = c \cdot\frac{b_2^m - 1}{b_2 - 1}$$
$$d \cdot (b_2 - 1) \cdot(b_1^n - 1) = c \cdot (b_1 - 1) \cdot (b_2^m - 1)$$

With $d < b_1$ and $c < b_2$.

Comment: Right.  I have deleted my earlier comment, @orlp.